# SCRIPT5007: Unable to get value of the property '0': object is null or undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-9, fileapi

I ran this code through Chrome and Firefox and it works well. Whenever I run it through Internet Explorer for testing purposes it will not work. I checked the javascript consule and I'm getting: **SCRIPT5007: Unable to get value of the property '0': object is null or undefined**. Can someone please tell me why this is coming up and what I can do to fix it?

```
$('#audiofile1').bind('change', function () {
    if (this.files[0].type != 'image/png') {
        $('#audiofile1').each(function () {
            $(this).after($(this).clone(true)).remove();
        });
        alert(this.files[0].name + ' is not a valid file type.');
    } else {
        if (this.files[0].size > '5000') {
            $('#audiofile1').each(function () {
                $(this).after($(this).clone(true)).remove();
            });
            var size = this.files[0].size;
            var maxSize = 100;
            var exceedingSize = size - maxSize;
            alert(this.files[0].name + ' exceeds the maximum file size');
        } else {
            $("#audiofile1").fadeTo(1500, 0.20);
            alert(this.files[0].name + ' was added successfully.');
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: of your actual JSON object "this" u can post example? If it has trailing commas thats your problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (this.files[0].type != 'image/png') {
```

Inside your event handler, jQuery makes `this` the DOM element for which the handler was registered. Either that element does not have a defined `files` property, or that property's value is `null` or `undefined`.

This is because Internet Explorer 9 and below do not support the [File API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh673542%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). You should probably just skip binding the handler if the File API is not available:

```
if ($('#audiofile1')[0].files) {
    $('#audiofile1').bind('change', function () {
        // ...
    });
}
```

Comment: Ahh I see what you're saying. I'll give that a try!

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, [IE only supports the HTML5 File API starting with version 10.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh673542%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)  Thus, in IE 9, there is no `.files` property to access at all.

Unfortunately, I don't know any way to work around this, except to tell your users to upgrade and/or to provide some alternative (likely server-side) method for users on older browsers to accomplish whatever it is you're doing.  In your case, assuming that you're eventually uploading the files to the server for further processing anyway, you could just skip the client-side checks on browsers that don't support them, and simply tell your users what kind of files will be accepted.

Answer (score 0):

I am getting this (same/similar) error when attempting to Open a Jquery UI Dialog :
SCRIPT5007: Unable to get value of the property '_focusTabbable': object is null or undefined.

The change that I made that appears to have caused this error...:
a) Change to Jquery 1.9.1
b) Change to Jquery UI 1.10.1
c) Added 'appendTo' option to the dialog invocation.

a) + b) > c)

I needed to do (c) because I had added (15) jquery dialogs to an existing page that previously had some subform elements disposed as hide/show div elements.  I wanted to gain the jquery dialog functionality including modality.  Problem was that the subform elements were rewritten by jquery by appending to the document, outside of the  elements, thus formfields in the dialogs were no longer included when the form is submitted.

Anyway does anyone have a better solution than the above to this issue ?